# Converting a JDO query to Objectify query

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo, objectify

I've been thinking on how to covert this JDO query to Objectify query but so I can only find `listByProperty` function which I cannot apply such filters like this:

```
Date expiry = new Date(new Date().getTime() - MAX_TIME);
Query query = pm.newQuery(User.class, "someProperty == null && " +
          "lastModified < dateParam");
query.declareParameters("java.util.Date dateParam");
query.setOrdering("lastModified asc, created asc");
query.setRange(0, 2);
List<User> users = (List<User>) query.execute(expiry);
```

**Code for the listByProperty:**

```
public List<T> listByProperty(String propName, Object propValue)
{
    Query<T> q = ofy().query(clazz);
    q.filter(propName, propValue);
    return asList(q.fetch());
}
```

I am not familiar with JDO queries so hopefully you can share some insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Objectify3:

```
ofy.query(User.class)
    .filter("someProperty", null)
    .filter("lastModified <", expiry)
    .order("lastModified")
    .order("created")
    .limit(2);
```

In Objectify4:

```
ofy.load().type(User.class)
    .filter("someProperty", null)
    .filter("lastModified <", expiry)
    .order("lastModified")
    .order("created")
    .limit(2);
```

Comment: What are the valid types that can used to filter with the lessthan/greaterthan "<" operator, if I use java.util.Date would it filter objects with "date" attribute less than the "expiry"?

Comment: Yes - pass in objects of the same type as the field you are filtering by on the User class.  If Objectify can store it, it can filter by it.